# What is the difference between @{} @code{} and @function{} in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I am learning server-side. Blazor .

I have read the code of some projects and found some that use:

```
@{
}
```

and some that use:

```
@code{
}
```

and others that use:

```
@function{
}
```

to mark the code block.

I would like to know the difference between these. Thank you.

Comment: I think this link has everything that you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: @DiógenesFrança Thanks a lot. That's what I need.

Comment: `@code` is for razor components. But I'm still puzzled. I can declare a function in `@{}`, thought I can't declare a property?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`@` for directive(s)

`@code{ }` [2] should be used. `@function{ }` [3] is still effect, in case of method, not recommended in current version.

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#code

[3] https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#functions

See document for all cases https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#functions

Answer (score 6):

@{
}

You cannot use **function** or **set get** property under @{} instead, you can use only declare. for example:

```
@{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
}
```

But below code will show you error as I am using **function** here:

```
@{
    public DateTime GetDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

@code{
}

you can write any **C# code** under **@code {}** for example:

```
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public Guid id { get; set; }

    AccessoryDto accessory;
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty)
            accessory = new AccessoryDto();
        else
            accessory = GetAccessory(id);
        return Task.FromResult(accessory);
    }

    void cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/accessories");
    }
}
```

@function{
}

@function does the same thing as @code but now a days, **@code** is **recommended** to use.

Apart from this, you can use **@ sign** to use condition, loop and so on. for example:

```
@if (id == null)
{
    <h1>Create</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1>Edit</h1>
}
```

and

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var accessory in Accessories)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@accessory.Name</td>
        <td>@accessory.Description</td>
        <td>
            <a href='/editaccessory/@accessory.Id'>Edit</a>  |
            <a href='/delete/@accessory.Id'>Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Moreover, you can **@()** for expression. for example:

```
<a href="@($"employee/{employeeId}")">View</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

After I was looking to learn what are  the difference between  @  @()  @{}  @:  @code{} . I would like to share the summary of the differences

In Blazor the default Razor language is HTML. The following symbols can be used to integrate C# code into an Blazor file

@    Implicit Razor expressions To render C# code in the HTML zone.

@()  The same as @ but Explicit Razor expressions

@{}   to integrate C# code into the HTML zone. this code isn't rendered like the code in @().

@:    To insert explicit text if you are inside the @{} block,  you can do this by adding the @: sign

@code{}    The @code block enables you to add fields, properties, and methods to a Blazor Page

```
@page "/test"

@s1
@(s1)
<br />
@{
    Random r = new Random();
}
@(r.Next())
<br />
@(s2)
@{
    @:(s2)
}
@((MarkupString)s2)

@code {
    string s1 = "Hello";
    string s2 = "<h1>Hello</h1>";
}
```